# Unity selecting appropriate container

Tags: unity-container

I'm using Unity for IoC, and I want to follow the principles laid out in [How not to do dependency injection](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/how-not-to-do-dependency-injection-the-static-or-singleton-container). So no global available container, no `mContainer.Resolve<Type>()` throughout the code, but constructor injection.

My issue is applying these principles with multiple containers. My application compares many products (objects that follow a shared model), and each product is configured by it's own container.

I'm looking for a way to make every 'product' (which can be viewed as an object with many children) use it's own container without specifying that container. These container could be child containers or named containers, I don't think that makes any difference?

I have looked into unity extensions, but haven't found the answer yet.

Comment: A different container for every object? I'm sure I misinterpret something, but you could you clarify please?

Comment: I don't want a container for **every** object. However, I have multiple 'products' (objects that derive from the same class hierarchy but behave differently due to their specific details). Every product should use it's own container to register it's own derived classes.

Comment: Well, I can understand having multiple containers for performances reasons, MAYBE, but as soon as you'll have a link between two entities from two different containers, you won't have a good time imho. For different implementations of a same base/abstract class, I'd definitely use named registrations, or in some case factories, if the proper resolution is only known at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

When I was writing this question, I was kind of lost in the details while introducing Dependency Injection in an existing code base. The question wasn't too well written, I was aware of that at the time, but I didn't know how to improve my explanation of the problem.

That being said, here's how I solved my issue.

As I've said, I have an application that compares multiple products. These products can be thought of as multiple implementations of the same interface. So I need to use these multiple implementations concurrently. All these products are actually complex objects, with multiple dependencies, and many of those objects are constructed with runtime data and therefore are not created by *construction injection*.

My problem was with the objects that weren't created by constructor injection. By the time they needed to be constructed, I had lost the context of the current product, and couldn't create the appropriate types for that product.

I created child containers for every product to define which implementations were needed for specific interfaces per product.

At some point, I'm creating a product instance. This is the only place in the code where I ask for the appropriate container (like: give me the child container for product X). All I needed to do then (at product creation), was to create a factory object (that has a reference to the appropriate container), and pass it along to every object that needed to resolve components dynamically, i.e. not by constructor injection.

That was the missing link. I'm still wondering if the factory really needs to know the container, but I can live with that.

I hope this helps someone.